# Using HtmlAgility to extract text inside a span

Tags: vb.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

Requirement: Extract the text "Lossless" out.

```
<td nowrap="nowrap" align="center">
<span class="gen">4:59<br /><span style="color: red">Lossless</span></span>
</td>
```

I could only extract the whole text "4:59Lossless" from it by:

```
Dim divnodes As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@nowrap='nowrap']//span[@class='gen']")

        If Not divnodes Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox(div.InnerText)
        End If
```

I also tried

```
Msgbox(div.Attributes("style").Value)
```

but no work.

Could you address me. Thank you ~

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding "/span"

```
           Dim divnodes As HtmlNodeCollection =doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@nowrap='nowrap']//span[@class='gen']/span")

            If divnodes IsNot Nothing Then
            For each div as HtmlNode in divnodes2
              MsgBox(div.InnerText)
            Next               
            End If
```

Comment: Incidentally, you can use `If divnodes IsNot Nothing Then` instead, as recommended in Microsoft's [Visual Basic Coding Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/coding-conventions).

Comment: Thank you @AndrewMorton for the useful link. Yeah. They suggest using "IsNot" instead of "Not...Is". Answer updated!